# How to ? res.render send one element in object to client

Tags: node.js, express, hogan.js

I try to send JSON data to client (I use hogan template). I send all of object and it work.

```
Users.find({}, function(err, data){
res.render('users/show', {title : 'show users',  users : JSON.stringify(data)});
);
```

client :

```
<p>{{ users }}</p>
```

and the browser will show like :
    [{"email":"01@mail.com","_id":"5434ef07b3f1f6cc3145b1f2","__v":0}]

But I want only email to be shown in my browser, it didn't work. For example :

```
<p>{{ users.email }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `users : JSON.stringify(data)` to `users : data` in your `res.render()`.

Then since you have an array, so you need to specify the index first:

```html
<p>{{ users[0].email }}</p>
```